# Spring MVC-HIbernate Hibernate Version - hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hi New To Spring MVC + Hibernate . Previously I Was Using hibernate core-5.1.0.Final Than Session.createCriteria() Was Working Fine. But Now Its Deprecated

So I Started Using hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final. I Learnt How to Use session.getCriteriaBuilder() And Its Working Fine.

But Problem Is I Dont Know How To Insert Update  In Database After Using hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.  Previously When I Was Using hibernate core-5.1.0.Final I Was Able To Insert Update Easily By Using  session.save(); session.flush();session.close();

But Now When I Use session.save(); session.flush();session.close(); With hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final Im Getting This Error Message :--

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in
>   progress

My Code Is This :

```
public class UsersDAOImpl implements UsersDAO  {

    private static SessionFactory factory ;

    public String registerUser(String userEmailOruserName,String userPassword)
    {



                factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

                   Session session = factory.openSession();

                         Users us = new Users();
                         us.setUserEmailOruserName(userEmailOruserName);
                         us.setUserPassword(userPassword);

                         try
                         {

                         session.save(us);

                         }

                         catch(HibernateException he)
                         {

                              return "Error";
                         }


                             session.flush();
                             session.close();



                        return "Sucessfull" ;




}
```

Console Error Messages : -

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress


Oct 23, 2017 1:42:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/MaharashtraMeinJobDhundho] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress] with root cause
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3461)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1421)
    at com.programcreek.MaharashtraMeinJobDhundho.DAO.UsersDAOImpl.registerUser(UsersDAOImpl.java:58)
    at com.programcreek.MaharashtraMeinJobDhundho.Controller.RegisterUserController.registerUser(RegisterUserController.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please Tell Me How To Insert Update In DataBase With Using  hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final. I Read Lots Of Article How To Do It But Not Able To Implement It

Comment: Why on earth are you capitalizing every single damn word? Are you trying to make it as hard as possible to help you?

Comment: your exception itself is describing no transaction is available for insert/update.Start a transaction/or get active transaction

Comment: @glennsl  sorry about every single  damn capital word  from now i wont use capital word

Answer (score 0):

Your exception says you are saving/updating a record without an active transaction.

trying something like this.

```
try{
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();  
    session.save(us);
    tx.commit(); 
}
catch(){
}
```

Comment: thanx for help now im able to add record in database after adding transaction in code

Comment: thanx for help now im able to add record in database after adding transaction in code  but please can u clearify why    hibernate core-5.1.0.Final   and   hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final  behaving differently   the same above code i used with  hibernate core-5.1.0.Final  working perfectly without   Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();    also please explain what  session.flush() do when i used session.flush() with tx.commit() i was getting same error that "no transaction is in progress"  again thanx i was stuck in this error for 2 days u saved me

Comment: It may depend on the configurations, if by default all the db interactions are transaction then you will get this error. I don't think u got this error due to hibernate upgrade, this error may be due to spring configurations.

Comment: what spring configurations?? u mean dispatcher-servlet.xml  file  or hibernate.cfg.xml  file   should i paste my both xml files here to show u i want to know how we can configure db interactions